# Remove from hash by key and return value

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to remove from hash by key and return removed value. i.e. this code:

```
var a = attributes['a']
delete attributes['a']
```

in single line. Smth like Ruby's `delete`:

```
a = attributes.delete(:a)
```

Comment: You can always write your own function.

Comment: But this function would have to take two arguments, not one.

Answer (score 7):

In one single line, yes :

```
var a = attributes['a']; delete attributes['a'];
```

In one single simple statement, no.

You can imagine a function doing it for you but as you can't pass the attribute in ES5 but only its name or its value, you'd have to use two arguments :

```
function deleteAndReturn(map, key) {
    var a = map[key];
    delete map[key];
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Dammmmmmn. I was writing the same thing ;).

Comment: @Matt I used my time machine to copy on you. It's super effective.

Comment: @BaburUsenakunov: dystroy ends his answer with `In one single statement, no.`. You cannot do it.